# Passing XML configuration file to @SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I am trying to pass XML configuration file to my test class with code below

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = { SpringBootApp.class }, properties = {"locations=classpath:config/beans-import.xml" }, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

But none of the beans are loaded from the configuration file into the context and beans not found error is thrown in auto wiring. Does anybody know how to pass a configuration file under `resources` to `@SpringBootTest`. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test` in your dependencies or `org.springframework:spring-test`?

Comment: @OnurAktaş spring-test.

Comment: @ImportResource("classpath:config/beans-import.xml") ?

Comment: Also try `@EnableAutoConfiguration` with `@ImportResource`

Comment: There should be an `@ImportResource` for that on your `SpringBootApp` why load it in the test and not while running your app?

Comment: In my case, the following annotation helped (instead of `properties`):
`@ContextConfiguration("/config/beans-import.xml")`